# How does the author derive this (Difference of analytic functions evaluated at two points)

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]
The conditions are $f:U\to V$ is holomorphic and injective.

I basically have 2 questions:

Q1) How did the author get $f(z)-f(z_0)=a(z-z_0)^k+G(z)$?

Q2) What does "vanishing to order $k+1$" mean?

---

I have tried to guess the reason, letting $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots$, then

$\begin{aligned}
f(z)-f(z_0)=a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z^2-z_0^2)+\dots
\end{aligned}$

I can see how to pull out a factor of $z-z_0$ since $z^n-z_0^n$ has a factor $z-z_0$, but not sure how to derive what the author got.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A holomorphic function $G(z)$ vanishes to order (at least) $n$ at $z_0$ if $G^{(m)}(z_0)=0$ for all $m<n$.

To get $f(z)-f(z_0)=a(z-z_0)^k+G(z)$, just let $a(z-z_0)^k$ be the first nonzero term (after the constant term) in the Taylor expansion of $f(z)$ around $z_0$, and $G(z)$ be the rest of the terms.  We have $k\geq 2$ since the degree $1$ Taylor coefficient is $f'(z_0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Very clear explanation.